# Add character to every number via Regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a very basic question which i just can not get my head around. I do have a text document like this:

```
This is 5 a test!
This 3 is a test!
This is a 9 test!
```

and i want it to look like this:

```
This is 5c a test!
This 3c is a test!
This is a 9c test!
```

Means i want to add a 'c' to every number i find. I tried this:

```
Find what: [0-9]+]
Replace with: $1c
Search Mode: Regular expression
```

but i am obviously doing something wrong because it is not working. Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you try `[0-9]+]` with those strange unmatched brackets?

Comment: @Heinzi Betting it's a typo in the question, given the proximity of `+`, `]` and `Enter` on many keyboards.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You almost got it right.

You want to search for `([0-9]+)`
And replace that with `$1c`

You use `(   )` to create a capture group, so $1 works.

Alternatively, you can replace with `$0c` instead, then you don't need to use a capture group.

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Just curious if there's a difference in that pattern and looking for `\d+`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Depending on yoru regex flavour, `\d` can match Unicode digits [from other scripts](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). Note that this is not the case for PCRE, which is apparently what Notepad++ uses. In any case, I'd usually favour `\d` if I want numerical digits, but `[0-9]` if I explicitly want those characters (e.g. when scraping a defined format that's limited to ASCII characters).

Comment: Indeed, \d would've worked just as well. I kept the [0-9] syntax because OP already tried that, and the other answer uses \d.

Answer (score 13):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+`
- Replace with: `$0c`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Result for given example:**

```
This is 5c a test!
This 3c is a test!
This is a 9c test!
```

Comment: What does wrap around do?